# Hiding 'Add to Cart' button on WooCommerce variable products

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to hide the `Add to Cart` button when a variable product is at a certain stock level (so retailers and wholesalers see `out of stock` at different stock levels). I have managed to do this for simple products but am really struggling as to how to implement this with variable products.

For the simple product I put

```
<?php 
if ( $product->get_stock_quantity() <= 2 && current_user_can('customer')) { 
    echo 'out of stock'; 
} else { //'add to cart' button }
```

I don't know if it's possible to implement something similar for variable products? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have tried for variable products?

Comment: What should the outcome be? Do you want to show in / out of stock per variation? Or for the entire product at once?

Answer (score 0):

Get the product id from the woocommerce and then implement your code as it is with the id of that product.

Comment: Bad solution. As it is not really repeatable like this

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I think your if statement is evaluating incorrectly; you're missing brackets.

Try

```
<?php if ( ($product->get_stock_quantity() <= 2) && (current_user_can('customer'))) { 
echo 'out of stock'; } else { //'add to cart' button }
```